# How do I use a lemma from a Coq library?

Tags: coq

I am trying to use the lemma eqb_sym from this library:
https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.Equalities.html

I tried "Require Import Coq.Structures.Equalities." and "Require Import BoolEqualityFacts" but neither let me use the lemma eqb_sym. Coq complains that it can't find the lemma in the current environment. In general, when I find a lemma that I would like to use from a library in https://coq.inria.fr/library/, where do I find the right module to import and is "Require Import Module-Name" the right way to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eqb_sym` lemma is defined inside a functor parameterized by a module of type `BooleanEqualityType'`.  To use it, you must instantiate that functor and import it.  Here is a possible use for the standard type of natural numbers, `nat`:

```
Require Import Coq.Structures.Equalities.

(* We are defining an implementation of a module of
   type BooleanEqualityType'. You can check what fields are required
   by asking Coq to print BooleanEqualityType'. *)
Module N <: BooleanEqualityType'.

Definition t := nat.
Definition eq := @eq nat.
Lemma eq_equiv : Equivalence eq.
Proof. split; congruence. Qed.
Definition eqb := Nat.eqb.
Lemma eqb_eq : forall n m, eqb n m = true <-> eq n m.
Proof. (* Fill in here *) Admitted.

End N.

(* Instantiate the generic lemmas for our implementation *)
Module Import NBoolEqualityFacts := BoolEqualityFacts(N).

(* We can now use the lemma *)
Check eqb_sym.
```

Comment: Note that in a standard case like `nat`, the appropriate module is available in the standard library. `Require Import OrdersEx. Module NBoolEqualityFacts := BoolEqualityFacts(Nat_as_OT).`